# SQL consulta en EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

quiero hacer consultas sql manuales pero usando entity framework de .net .

ej:

```
select from database where id == 20 ;
```

y no :

```
Item algo = new Item();
algo.name =
algo.lastName =

algo.Add();
```

me entienden????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pregunta está entendible, a pesar que está mal redactada, primero vamos por ejemplos:

### SQL queries for entities

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

### Loading entities from stored procedures

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogs").ToList(); 
}
```

También puedes enviar parámetros:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogId = 1; 

    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogById @p0", blogId).Single(); 
}
```

### Writing SQL queries for non-entity types

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>( 
                       "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

### Sending raw commands to the database

Me late que esto es lo que estás buscando:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
        "UPDATE dbo.Blogs SET Name = 'Another Name' WHERE BlogId = 1"); 
}
```

Referencia: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907%28v=vs.113%29.aspx